# ubuntu-server unreachable using https://ubuntu:10000

Tags: server, hostname

I could reach my ubuntu-server via https://ubuntu:10000/ in a previous install of ubuntu server 16.04 LTS. Before I got that install fully configured, I reinstalled (changed to a different physical disk).

Now I can only reach it with its IP in my local subnet https://192.168.1.x:10000. https://ubuntu:10000/ gives me an error:

> name not resolved

Both installs include LAMP.

Not sure how to get it working via https://ubuntu:10000/ again. I have checked the hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 ubuntu
```

`resolv.conf` has

```
75.75.75.75
75.75.76.76
8.8.8.8
```

as name servers.

Comment: Crossposted here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/428117/cannot-reach-my-ubuntu-server-via-https-ubuntu10000

Comment: @An0n: That shouldn't matter since `ubuntu` is listed in `/etc/hosts`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was cross-posted (see above).